# Why prettier is ignoring only semicolon rule in my config?

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, prettier, editorconfig

I have been trying to resolve this for quite a while now: I am using a `settings.json` file that sits in `.vscode` directory in the root of my project to configure prettier. All of the rules works except the `"prettier.semi": false`.

`settings.json` :

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "explorer.compactFolders": false,
  "prettier.arrowParens": "avoid",
  "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "prettier.tabWidth": 2,
  "prettier.trailingComma": "none",
  "prettier.semi": false
}
```

Any ideas what can be overriding it?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have any `editorconfig ` file or a `prettierrc` file?

Comment: no, not really, I tried to set it up before I had the above, but needed to do something wrong because it did not format anything

Comment: Did you set prettier as the default formatter? `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"` also do you have any other formatterS?

Comment: Solved: I had path to a config file set in the extension settings. Cleared it and now .prettierrc works just fine :)

Comment: I had to uncheck - Prettier: Use Editor Config